# PHP email - want to send to different emails

Tags: php, forms, email

**Currently:**

I have the PHP form below, where users select one of the checkboxes a notification comes as to which location they are looking to book.

**Goal:**

I would like it to now be that when someone clicks Canterbury an email is sent to email1@gmail.com, when to Broadstairs - email2@gmail.com, and when to deal - email3@gmail.com

I have been going in circles trying to make the changes but I get in a mess.

FYI I don't mind changing the checkboxes into a dropdown, but I would rather keep it this way.

**Current PHP section:**

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors',0);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$error = '';

if(isset($_POST['send']))
{
        $name = $_REQUEST['Name'];
        $telephone = $_REQUEST['Telephone'];
        $email = $_REQUEST['Email'];
        $message = $_REQUEST['Message'];
        $headers = "From: $email";
        $subject = "Web Contact Data";
        $selectedProjects  = 'None';
            if(isset($_POST['projects']) && is_array($_POST['projects']) && count($_POST['projects']) > 0){
                $selectedProjects = implode(', ', $_POST['projects']);
            }

        $fields = array();
        $fields["Name"] = $name;
        $fields["Telephone"] = $telephone;
        $fields["Email"] = $email;
        $fields["Message"] = $message;
        $fields["Location"] = $selectedProjects;

         $to = "email4@gmail.com" ; // change all the following to $_POST

        $body = "You have recieved the following information:\n\n";
        foreach($fields as $key => $value)
        {
            $body .= sprintf("%20s: %s\n",$key,$value);
        } // end foreach($fields as $key => $value)

        $subject2 = "Thank you for contacting us.";
        $autoreply = "<html><body><p>Dear " . $name . ",</p><p>Message goes here.</p></body></html>"; 
        $headers2  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
        $headers2 .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
        $headers2 .= 'From: email4@gmail.com' . "\r\n";

        $send=false;
        if($name == '')
        {
            $error = "You did not enter your name, please try again.";
            selected_values();
        }
        $send=false;
        if($telephone == '')
        {
            $error = "You did not enter your telephone number, please try again.";
            selected_values();
        }
        elseif(!preg_match("/^[[:alnum:]][a-z0-9_.'+-]*@[a-z0-9-]+(\.[a-z0-9-]{2,})+$/", $email))
        {
            $error = "You did not enter a valid email address, please try again.";
            selected_values();
        }
        else
        {
            $send = mail($to, $subject, $body, $headers);
            $send2 = mail($email, $subject2, $autoreply, $headers2);

            if(!isset($error) && !$send)
            {
                $error = "We have encountered an error sending your mail, please notify [email]email4@gmail.com[/email].";
            }
            else
            {
                unset($_REQUEST['Name']);
                unset($_REQUEST['Email']);
                unset($_REQUEST['Telephone']);
                unset($_REQUEST['Message']);
            }
    } // end else
}// end of if(isset($_POST['send']))
?>
```

**And the HTML form is this:**

```
<form method="post" action="./lead.php">
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php
        if(isset($error))
            echo '<div class="register_error">'.$error.'</div>';
        if(isset($send) &&  $send== true){
            =echo '<div class="contact-send-green">Thank you for your message.</div>';
        }
        if(!isset($_POST['send']) || isset($error))
        ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="checkbox" name="projects[]" value="Broadstairs">
        <label for="type2">Broadstairs</label>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="projects[]" value="Canterbury">
        <label for="type2">Canterbury</label>
        <br /><br />
        <input type="checkbox" name="projects[]" value="Deal">
        <label for="type2">Deal</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <textarea name="Message" rows="5" cols="29"><?php if(isset($_REQUEST['Message'])) echo $_REQUEST['Message']; ?></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
        <input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Message" id="send-email">
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: you have no end `</form` tag. is that a copy paste error? and what behaviour are you actually seeing? any erorrs? ps. dont put real email addresses in questions.

Comment: You should remove those email addresses from public view as soon as possible.

Comment: Is it single selection or is it multiple? As in, can they select more than one option? If it's only 1, then a simple `switch(){}` will do the trick, otherwise

Comment: @MattHB thank you.. i see they are removed.. rookie error. There are actually no error messages when I have been playing, just the emails are not received.

Comment: @Epodax Yes, it's single selection.. 1 or the other.

Comment: I updated my answer to include the foreach loop you require for multiple selections

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 3 issues with the script you have provided

1. You want to select only a single email address however, you are using the name `projects[]` as the checkbox names - this will create an array, however since HTML5; if you use a name multiple times even without the `[]` it will create an array.
2. Given the above, you should most definitely as you mentioned change to a `<select>` box, or alternatively `<radio>` buttons.
3. You should **not** use `$_REQUEST` unless absolutely needed, you are providing an easy oppurtunity for sql injection.

Here is an example of how I would do it.

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="./lead.php">
<ul>
    <li>
        <?php
            if(isset($error)) echo '<div class="register_error">'.$error.'</div>';
            if(isset($send) &&  $send== true) echo '<div class="contact-send-green">Thank you for your message.</div>';
        ?>
    </li>
    <li>
        <label for="Broadstairs"><input type="radio" name="projects" id='Broadstairs' value="Broadstairs"> Broadstairs</label>
        <label for="Canterbury"><input type="radio" name="projects" id='Canterbury' value="Canterbury">Canterbury</label>
        <label for="Deal"><input type="radio" name="projects" id='Deal' value="Deal">Deal</label>
    </li>
    <li>
        <textarea name="Message" rows="5" cols="29"><?=(strlen($_POST['Message'])>0) ? $_POST['Message'] : ''; ?></textarea>
    </li>
    <li>
        <button type='submit'>Send Message</button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

**And your PHP**

```
<?php

if (!empty($_POST)) {
    // Dispatch message to selected office
    $name       = $_POST['Name'];
    $telephone  = $_POST['Telephone'];
    $email      = $_POST['Email'];
    $message    = $_POST['Message'];
    $subject    = "Web Contact Data";

    // To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'From: My website <my-email@example.com>' . "\r\n";

    if ($_POST['projects'] == 'Canterbury') $to = "example@gmail.com" ;
    elseif ($_POST['projects'] == 'Broadstairs') $to = "example@gmail.com" ; 
    else $to = "example@gmail.com" ;

    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);


    // Dispatch "Thank You" email
    $subject = "Your message has been received!";

ob_start();
?>
<html>
<body>
<p>Dear <?=$name?></p>
<p>Thank you for contacting us,</p>
<p>We have received your message and will respond to you as soon as possible.</p>
<p>This is an automatic response to your inquiry and it is not necessary to reply.</p>
<p>Thank you,</p>
</body>
</html>
<?
$message = ob_get_flush();

    mail($email, $subject, $message, $headers)
}

?>
```

I would recommend [Google Recaptcha](https://www.google.com/recaptcha) too.

Hope this helps

Comment: Change your checkboxes into a select box or radio buttons and you're laughing

Comment: BRILLIANT - it works :) There's only 1 small issues.. when I receive the auto-reply it comes via the host companies mail address myusername@hostcompany.com

Comment: See my updated answer, you were resetting the "From" because you recreated `$header`

Comment: wow.. ok.. i've put that all in but not the page doesn't actually load haha.. it's just a white page.. would that be something to do with the doc type now changing?

Comment: Add `ini_set('display_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` to the top of the page, what does it say

Comment: For your DOCType just use `<!doctype html>` == HTML5

Answer (score 4):

For single selection a simple [switch(){}](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) would do the magic.

```
switch($_POST['projects']){
   case "Broadstairs":
      $to = "email@email.com";
      break;
   case "Canterbury":
      $to = "email@email.com";
      break;
   case "Deal":
      $to = "email@email.com";
      break;
}
```

And then remove the [] from the input names as you won't need them to be a array. (As such:)

```
<input type="checkbox" name="projects" value="Broadstairs">
```

And then perhaps considering using some JS/jQuery to check that only 1 is selected at a time?

Comment: Thanks.. what do I replace in the full PHP with the top section?

Comment: I'm guessing that the `$to` is the deal / canterbury / broadstairs recipient, so just replace the switch with your `$to = "email4@gmail.com" ;` line.

Comment: Why remove the `[]`? What if he want's multiple selections? I believe it's converted to an array regardless anyway

Comment: Because I asked him if it was single selection or multiple, he answered single selection @Zanderwar - Read the comments on his question.

Comment: He should use radio then

Comment: @Zanderwar _"FYI I don't mind changing the checkboxes into a dropdown, but I would rather keep it this way."_ - In OP's question, besides, tell him, not me.

Comment: I'm open to all options haha :) which works best.. 

I have put this into the original (I know this isn't a java, but wanted to show you - https://jsfiddle.net/j76yo120/1/ ) and removed the [] from the input but I still doesn't work.

Comment: @Lozano the link you provided with jsfiddle, it's a mess? only php code there, no html, no js? and the bottom right corner there's mix of code and what not.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `if`, `elseif`, and `else` condition to your code.

Replace `$to = "email1@email.com" ;` with following code

```
if($_POST['projects'] == 'Broadstairs')
{
    $to = "email2@email.com";
}
else if($_POST['projects'] == 'Canterbury')
{
$to = "email3@email.com";
}
else if($_POST['projects'] == 'Deal')
{
    $to = "email4@email.com";
}
else
{
    $to = "email5@email.com";
}
```